# Loading images from another domain in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-image

When loading a page in a webview, I can't reference images on another server - if the page the webview loads is example.com, then

img src="http://anotherexample.com/image.jpg" will not load.

Is there a work-around for this?

Comment: You should be able to normally as far as I remember. Is your main page URL HTTPS?

Comment: No, it's HTTP ... one thing I noticed though, in the source of the mobile-friendly page (goMobi site), the externally-referenced images don't actually say "http://" in the code, just //.  

It shows img src="//thedomain.com/theimage.jpg"

This works in all browsers and in the mobile browser, think that's what is causing the webview to choke?

Comment: Seems unlikely that the relative scheme URL would cause this to fail given it's standard (I think), but you could certainly experiment and see for sure.

Comment: @RonRule how did you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

its amazing, but for me problem solved by adding shouldOverrideUrlLoading:

```
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
}
```